# Uncaught exception inside onNext being propagated to RxJava global exception handler

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

Following is a simplified example of a problem that I'm trying to tackle. In my code base, the problem is occurring with a PublishSubject but Observable can be used to reproduce this problem.

**Problem:**

I've an uncaught exception in `onNext()` of the subscriber that propagates the exception to the RxJava's global exception handler which results into a crash. However this is not the desired behavior. The objective is to handle uncaught exceptions gracefully.

**Question:**

Why is `onError()` not being called for the uncaught exception? What method(s) can I use to catch such uncaught exceptions?

**Quick solution:**

I can use `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler` to cope with this situation but I'd rather keep this solution as the last resort if we don't have any other solution to deal with the problem at hand.

**Code:**

```
Observable.just(true)
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        String x = null;
                        x.getBytes();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) { <--- NOT CALLED UPON EXCEPTION
                        System.out.println("inside test observable onError");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
12-03 11:09:01.454 4750-4750/? E/MDMApplication: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION IN APP: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mdm.app/mdm.connector.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at mdm.connector.app.MainActivity$1.onNext(MainActivity.java:63)
        at mdm.connector.app.MainActivity$1.onNext(MainActivity.java:59)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:103)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:64)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableScalarXMap$ScalarDisposable.run(ObservableScalarXMap.java:248)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableJust.subscribeActual(ObservableJust.java:35)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12036)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual(ObservableMap.java:33)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12036)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12036)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribeWith(Observable.java:12088)
        at mdm.connector.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Observer`s are not allowed to throw from their `onNext` methods. Lambda-based operators can throw and is handled for you by RxJava.

Comment: How does RxJava handle this for Lambda based operators? How does it distinguish between annonymous and lambda based operators. Please excuse my ignorance

Comment: Please take the opportunity and explore the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem above is, instead of using DisposableObserver we should use Consumer & Consumer in the subscribe method. This ensures that if there are any uncaught exceptions in the Consumer accept method, they will be caught in Consumer accept method instead of getting propagated to RxJava's global exception handler and resulting into a crash.

**Example:**

```
Observable.just(true)
.subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean> {
  public void accept(Boolean aboolean) {
      String x = null;
      x.getBytes();
  }
}, new Consumer<Throwable> {

  public void accept(Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace()
  }
});
```

If there is another better solution to cope with unhandled exceptions, please suggest that in comments